# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm using M1 chip and xCode 13.4.1. I get the following React Native error while executing the app in the simulator:

> The following build commands failed:
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/Ibra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mario-girhlsdkqiibhqhflwlyrybpo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E110.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
> (1 failure)

The problem persists even when I start a brand-new React Native project and try to execute it on iOS. What led to the error and how can it be fixed?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Described answers didn't help me, but I started reading error description: and I found out that in error description on the line 2: my folder's name was written partially. Folder name consisted 2 words divided by 1 space example: "My folder" in the error was written just "My". I just changed folder's name to "MyFolder" and it helped me to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and I figured out following solutions:

- What worked for me was `npx react-native-clean-project` and choosing `y` for all options, this will clean your React Native project by purging caches and modules, and reinstalling them again.

And here're some solutions that worked for others:

- If you're using nvm, `nvm unalias default` could solve the issue.
- This error could be due to Xcode can't find your node path, so try  `sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node`
- Delete `node_modules` then `cd ios && pod deintegrate` then reinstall node modules and `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

it has multiple solutions:

1. to solve this run this command in terminal in ios folder , `pod deintegrate` and install pod with the commad `pod install`
2. Restart your Mac , it is some time due to cache, delete derived data and logs from XCode -> Prefrences and location

Comment: A little correction. Up here, where you put `pod deintergrate` should be `pod deintegrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with below procedure:

1. Keychain Access > Cetificates > Login
2. Find any Apple Certificate that has the blue + symbol
3. Change it to "Use System Defaults" and close it.
4. You'll see a pop up. Type in your password to update settings.
5. Close Keychain. Open your project, clean build files and run.

Note: Mac with M1, Xcode 14.1

Answer (score 0):

change react native version 0.65.0
this working

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my react-native project,

I ran the project in XCode and got the above error without more explanation about why the application failed.

After that, I ran the project on Android, and then I got **Js errors** in Metro logs.

So I noticed that in order to view js errors I must run my project on android

**If you are working with react-native and Metro
And you are getting this error:**

**"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"**

**Try this solution:**

> Try to run your project **on Android** (or Chrome) and check if you
> are getting **JS errors** in Metro logs. Because in xCode **JS
> errors** not appear, and instead, the above error appears.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: It's node version mismatch version.

During the initial execution of 'pod install,' a file named **'.xcode.env.local'** was automatically generated in the '/ios' directory. This file contained the line

'$NODE_BINARY=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.8.0/bin/node.'

To know the exact path of Node I typed **"which node"** whatever you get just paste that path inside **'.xcode.env.local'** file.

I resolved the problem by updating this line only.

Answer (score -2):

Today I faced the same issue. Then downloaded Xcode 14.1. It is working without any issues.

Download it from here

```
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.1/Xcode_14.1.xip
```